# .Net core 6 Web api Fluent Validation - Calling addfluentvalidation() is deprecated and Response errors is missing

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, fluentvalidation, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm building a .net core 6 web API server.
I tried using Fluent Validation but I'm getting a warning that **Calling addfluentvalidation() is deprecated**.

[image]

Besides the warning, I was happy with the final result (an example of a 400 response)

[image]

So I tried looking for a better solution for using Fluent Validation without a deprecation warning.

I found this solution:

[image]

Which works but I'm now not satisfied with the response (The errors column now is missing)

Does anyone know why I'm not getting the errors column anymore? I have tried looking it online but no luck whatsoever.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post code as images. Code should be pasted as text, and formatted using Markdown. (The toolbar in the Stack Overflow editor can help you with this.) Code within images is harder to read, less accessible, can't be copied, and doesn't show up in relevant searches. Please [edit] your post to include the code as text; this will help you get better responses, and help prevent your question from getting deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following for auto validation.

```
services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
```